# C++ Read Access violation error

Tags: c++

I am currently getting an "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccce0." error and I have tried diagnose the problem...I think the problem comes in when my rule of 3 that I have defined comes in play and points me to here.

```
size_type size() const
    {   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mysize); <---------------------this line
    }
```

I'm actually not sure if there is any problem at all, I have been dwelling on this for days on end.

Below is my rule of three

```
ArrayStorage::ArrayStorage(){
     myArray = new string[7079];
}

ArrayStorage::~ArrayStorage(){
    delete[] _data;
    delete[] myArray;
}

ArrayStorage::ArrayStorage(const ArrayStorage &A) {
    _size = A.size();
    _data = new string [size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        _data[i] = A[i];
}

ArrayStorage& ArrayStorage::operator=(const ArrayStorage &A){
    if (this != &A) {
        delete [] _data;
        _size = A.size();
        _data = new string [A.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
             _data[i] = A[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

const string& ArrayStorage::operator[](int i) const{
    assert((i >= 0) && (i < size()));
    return _data[i];
}

string& ArrayStorage::operator[](int i){
    assert((i >= 0) && (i < size()));
    return _data[i];
}
```

Comment: A backtrace would be helpful here

Comment: Have you checked that `this` is valid? Do you have a backtrace from the debugger (you did check the application in the debugger?)? And why do you try to implement your own "array" instead of using any of the standard containers like `std::vector`?

Comment: I'd guess it's a pointer problem but it's impossible to tell without a stacktrace/backtrack. Somewhere you are calling size() at an adress where you think there's an ArrayStorage but there isn't. Since it's 0xccccce0 I'd go with an unitialized pointer.

Comment: Operating System?  Compiler name and version?

Comment: [Ameoo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1321957/ameoo) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/237525): Why not use breakpoints and watchlist to see the values before the error is thrown? That "this->_Mysize" is probably null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When uninitialized, stack variables are filled with 0xCC bytes if compiled with msvc. So 0xcccccce0 is probably the result of "this" being an uninitialized pointer variable on the stack plus _MySize offset in the object structure.

Comment: That's a good tip.  Could he have defined an `ArrayStorage*`, and not initialized it with a `new`?

Comment: Most probably. If the compiler is optimizing code and use method inlining, size() is translated to a direct field access, bypassing the vtable and leading to this access violation.

Comment: What vtable?  I've not seen anything to lead me to believe that `size` is a virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of obvious problems with your code: your destructor,
for example, does a `delete [] _data` and a `delete [] myArray`, but
`_data` is never initialized in your default constructor, and `myArray`
is never initialized in the copy constructor.  And you're assignment
operator can leave the object in an invalid state, if e.g. the `new`
fails.  (In general, if you have to test for self assignment, it's
almost certain that your assignment operator is broken.)  Either of
these problems result in undefined behavior which could corrupt the free
space arena, causing who knows what problem later.

Still, it would be interesting to see where `size` was called.  The
error message suggests an invalid `this`; that you've called the
function with an invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints/watchlist. I'm guessing that *this* is null.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's a pointer problem but it's impossible to tell without a stacktrace/backtrack. Somewhere you are calling size() at an adress where you think there's an ArrayStorage but there isn't. Since it's 0xccccce0 I'd go with an unitialized pointer.

For example, do you have something like this

```
ArrayStorage storage1;
ArrayStorage* storage2;
*storage2 = storage1;
```

That would result in this or a similar error, invalid this pointer.

And why are you writing your own std::vector?

Comment: Your second example won't compile; you can't define a reference without an initializer.